# asp.net assign value to variable when text control value is changed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code in the asp.net page that works assigning the value to dtStart, but how do I update the variable dtStart to what the user manually enters or modifies the datetime value in the txtStart control box? thanks.

```
protected void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtStart.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        dtStart = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If `txtStart.Text` contains text which *should* represent a `DateTime` then you can try to convert it to exactly that:

```
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParse(txtStart.Text, out dt))
    dtStart = dt;
```

If the value could be parsed to a `DateTime`, it will be set in the `dtStart` variable.  If not, it won't be.  (You can add an `else` clause, or invert the conditional entirely, to handle the condition where the string value couldn't be parsed to a `DateTime`.)

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you shouldn't use a simple textbox, but some Date picker control or jQuery.

A textbox can be usable only in that case if you force your user the set a properly formatted string as the date in the textbox and after that try to parse the string to DateTime according to David's answer.

Comment: not familiar withe the date picker control, but this control is useful for capturing datetime values or just dates? I need to capture start datetime and end datetime values and calculate the time lapsed.

Comment: I'm almost sure that there are a lot of DateTime controls that also capture Time. Or you can use a Date picker and a Time picker controller. That would be 2 then.